# how to get the window title of a process using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to go from the process name to the windows title.

e.g

'winamp.exe' -> '1. Britney Spears - Hit me baby one more time'

Thanks

Solution:

```
Dim p As Process

For Each p In Process.GetProcessesByName("winamp")

    MsgBox(p.MainWindowTitle.ToString)

Next
```

Comment: The `ToString` is utterly redundant in your code. `MainWindowTitle` is *already* a string!

Comment: Upvote for the window title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process_members(v=VS.80).aspx) class:

```
Process p = <Get process>
Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle)
```

Comment: Thanks.. the MainWindowTitle was what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the Filename as displayed in the Main Title Bar. This is the filename without the extension. Let's say that my Excel Workbook was named "ThisWorks.xlsx" This code returns "ThisWorks" without the file extension.

```
Function OpenAppFileNames(ByVal exeName As String) As String

    Dim p() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(exeName)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim x As Integer = UBound(p) + 1
    Dim Index As Long = 0
    Dim Title As String = ""
    Dim Result As String = ""
    Debug.Print(x)
    Do
        If i = x Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        Title = p(i).MainWindowTitle
        Result += vbNewLine & "Index " & Index + i & " = " & Title
        i = i + 1
        'MsgBox(Result)
    Loop Until i = x

    Return Result

End Function
```

p returns an array of integers starting at 0 (zero). If you know which order the processes are in, you can return the Title/Filename of the desired target.

Hope this helps... took me 3 weeks to find this answer.

Comment: Something to note, though, is that some apps only open a single instance, like MS Word and MS Excel, but that single instance may have multiple workbooks open.